# Build a custom terraform provider with Bazel

Tags: go, terraform, bazel

I'm trying to build a custom terraform provider as the link: https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/writing-custom-providers.html

Building with go is good.
But I couldn't make the build work with Bazel.

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_binary", "go_library")
load("@bazel_gazelle//:def.bzl", "gazelle")

# gazelle:prefix nox
gazelle(name = "gazelle")

go_library(
    name = "go_default_library",
    srcs = [
        "main.go",
        "provider.go",
        "resource_server.go",
    ],
    importpath = "nox",
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
    deps = [
        "@com_github_hashicorp_terraform//helper/schema:go_default_library",
        "@com_github_hashicorp_terraform//plugin:go_default_library",
        "@com_github_hashicorp_terraform//terraform:go_default_library",
    ],
)

go_binary(
    name = "nox",
    embed = [":go_default_library"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Got error:

```
/home/phuonglu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_phuonglu/1776745e55763483ee3d48d730fcf433/sandbox/linux-sandbox/935/execroot/__main__/external/com_github_hashicorp_terraform/vendor/google.golang
.org/api/option/option.go:163:54: cannot use "github.com/hashicorp/terraform/vendor/google.golang.org/api/internal".NewPoolResolver(int(w), o) (type *"github.com/hashicorp/terraform
/vendor/google.golang.org/api/internal".PoolResolver) as type "google.golang.org/grpc/naming".Resolver in argument to grpc.RoundRobin:
        *"github.com/hashicorp/terraform/vendor/google.golang.org/api/internal".PoolResolver does not implement "google.golang.org/grpc/naming".Resolver (wrong type for Resolve meth
od)
                have Resolve(string) ("github.com/hashicorp/terraform/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/naming".Watcher, error)
                want Resolve(string) ("google.golang.org/grpc/naming".Watcher, error)
```

Other error:

```
ERROR: /home/phuonglu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_phuonglu/ad07032ffc2f7bfb6275d446f85e98cd/external/com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go/aws/signer/v4/BUILD.bazel:3:1: @com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go//aws
/signer/v4:go_default_library: no such attribute 'importpath_aliases' in 'go_library' rule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error you pasted, it looks like two copies of the package `google.golang.org/grpc/naming` are being incorporated into the same binary. This causes a type error: these are different packages (even if the code is identical), and their exported types are not interchangeable.

The best thing to do here is probably to exclude the `vendor` directory in the `github.com/hashicorp/terraform` repository. You can add an argument to Gazelle in the corresponding `go_repository` rule in WORKSPACE. This prevents Gazelle from generating rules and resolving dependencies in that directory.

```
go_repository(
    name = "com_github_hashicorp_terraform",
    importpath = "github.com/hashicorp/terraform",
    # ...
    build_extra_args = ["-exclude=vendor"],
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get other error, using latest bazel, bazel_gazelle and io_bazel_rules_go:
ERROR: /home/phuonglu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_phuonglu/ad07032ffc2f7bfb6275d446f85e98cd/external/com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go/aws/signer/v4/BUILD.bazel:3:1: @com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go//aws
/signer/v4:go_default_library: no such attribute 'importpath_aliases' in 'go_library' rule

Comment: That indicates you need to upgrade rules_go or downgrade gazelle. gazelle 0.18.0 requires rules_go 0.19.0 at minimum.